# pd.read_excel crashes (hangs) on certain files

Tags: pandas, crash, conda, pystan, facebook-prophet

FOA I've never had pandas crash (freeze, loop infinitely) on me before. Second it's not the files, they were reading well before.

Doing a bit of research I stumbled upon [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23809) where the cause is traced back to pd._libs.cp36.
Another similar [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue35875)

I looked up my own pd.*libs to find diverse .py files like algos.cp38-win*....
A couple things fell to mind. First that I upgraded to python 3.8.
Environment is called work38 btw
But trying on a different environment didn't work

The only other thing is that I installed fbprophet. To install fbprophet I installed pystan.
To install pystan I had to run this command [as per their docs](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html)
`conda install libpython m2w64-toolchain -c msys2`.

There are many guides to installing pystan that encourage you to install in a particular order (first pystan, then numpy cython pandas etc). Idk if there's a reason for this.

In any case, my idea is that the code above f***ed up my whole anaconda environment with some c compilers and now pandas is broken in all environments, even if I pip uninstall & pip install --no-cache-dir pandas.

2 Questions:
First one is, do you know what's happening here? Could you explain me?
And second, any idea how I can repair this? Or must I uninstall anaconda an reinstall everything (then of course pip install -r requirements.txt)

Edit: Maybe the C compiler stuff is unrelated. I just let read_excel run for a painful amount of time and it returned a dataframe with 65000 rows and 250 columns.
I see that when I convert the xlsx to csv (with a CLI script) the csv contains a bunch of empty rows and columns.

TLDR: I have an xlsx file with 250 rows and ~20 columns but apparently the empty cells aren't empty?

Comment: Was everything in the new environment (**work38**) or were you also trying to make changes to **base**?

Comment: I ran all commands on work38